# Isolate points with same parcel but different x and y coordinates

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy, arcmap

I have a large list of 100000 points in shapefile format. These points have address, parcel number and x and y coordinates as attributes. I would like to know which and how many points have the same parcel but different x and y coordinates.

Comment: Would you be ok with a solution in arcpy? Model builder? you could add some more tags to the question.

Comment: im looking for a simpler way as I am running out of time...

Comment: well, arcpy will be very simple.  I'll post an answer presently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the arcpy script.  It will take a while to run, but should print out the information you need.  On the desktop, create a new text file call "script.py" (rename the extension to .py instead of .txt), right-click, Edit in IDLE, paste in the following code, change the paths, and then hit F5 to run it.

```
import arcpy

shp = r"C:\path\to\shapefile.shp"
output_csv = r"C:\path\to\output.csv"
print "Analyzing shapefile: " + shp
print "\nstarting cursor..."

parcel_dict = {}

with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(shp,("parcel_num_field","x_field","y_field")) as curse:
    for row in curse:
        parcel = row[0]
        coordinates = (row[1],row[2])
        if not parcel in parcel_dict.keys():
            parcel_dict[parcel] = [coordinates]
        else:
            if not coordinates in parcel_dict[parcel]:
                parcel_dict[parcel].append(coordinates)

print "  cursor finished."
print "\nparcel count: " + str(len(parcel_dict.keys()))

with open(output_csv, "w") as out:

    print >> out, "parcel_num, unique_coords"
    for key, value in parcel_dict.iteritems():
        print >> out, "{0},{1}".format(key, len(value))

print "full summary stored in " + out
```

Comment: wow thanks a lot. i will read and use attentively.

Comment: so I changed the paths to the necessary ones, I copied to Python 3.4.3 shell and hit enter but shows the following error for the first line(import arcpy) Error states:SyntaxError: multiple statements found while compiling a single statement

Comment: Nevermind, I got it to work. I pasted it in the Arcmap python command line by using the execfile command. Thanks

Comment: What is the processing time for 100,000 entries? It would be nice to have a formula to be able to predict how long it would take. Thanks

Comment: just add a print statement to print at every 100 and use that as a metric. or adapt some of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13890935/timestamp-python) information.

Comment: Unfortunately it is already running and the ArcMap window is not responding... I was thinking of doing some other stuff while it runs. Although what stuff depends on how long the run will take...

Comment: Anyone able to give me a rough estimate?

Comment: You could just create another script like I described in the question, and start that one (minus the csv output) and then use any number of timing methods to time the first 100 records.  If you are worried about time in general, you should run stuff like this with a subset to get a metric ahead of time.